# Is it possible to use the YIELD() function in Excel to compute the yield of an Italian government bond?

Tags: fixed-income, bond-yields, yield

I'm interested in using the YIELD() function in Excel to compute the yield of an Italian government bond.  The bond in question is:

0.750% 15-January-2018

Italian government bonds have special pricing conventions.  According to http://help.derivativepricing.com/1311.htm, yields are calculated using annual compounding even though coupons are semi-annual.

According to http://help.derivativepricing.com/1298.htm, the final period yield method is "compound yield".

If we price the bond at 100 and settle the bond on 12-January-2018 (a few days before the maturity date), is it possible to hack the YIELD() function in Excel to solve for a yield of 0.746739%, as in the second screen print below?

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: In this govt document (in English) the formula for yield is given on page 19 and an example on page 22. Basically it is actual/365 day count and $P=CF_1 (1+y)^{-t1}+\cdots+CF_n (1+y)^{-tn}$ so it is very simple and standard http://www.dt.tesoro.it/export/sites/sitodt/modules/documenti_en/debito_pubblico/presentazioni_studi_relazioni/Which-Government-bond-for-what-kind-of-investor---Forum-P.A.-2007.zip.pdf

Comment: Thank you.  Is it just Actual/365 in the final period?  Also, importantly, can we use the YIELD() function in Excel to compute this?

Comment: The standard day count convention for BTPs (fixed coupon bonds) is Actual/Actual. The screenshot you took actually lists this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. As you have mentioned, Italian BTPs pay semi-annual coupons, but the discount frequency for yield is annual. The price-yield formula is therefore:

$$ P + AI = \frac{c/f}{(1 + y/f')^{t_0 f'}} + \cdots + \frac{100 + c/f}{(1 + y/f')^{t_nf'}}, $$
where $f = 2$ and $f'=1$.

The `YIELD` function in Excel can only handle scenarios where $f = f'$.